# Como tener una imagen especifica en cada pregunta

Tags: javascript, html, css

Cuando se ejecuta el código muestra preguntas aleatorias, pero también me gustaría que me muestre una imagen en esas preguntas. Y hacer que funcione para un teléfono celular.
¿me pueden ayudar con este código? no pude hacerlo yo mismo, lo intenté pero es complicado, quiero que todas las preguntas me muestren una foto. Por ejemplo: que cada pregunta tenga una imagen diferente.

¿Se podría hacer?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#remaining-time").hide();
  $("#start").on("click", trivia.startGame);
  $(document).on("click", ".option", trivia.guessChecker);
});

var trivia = {
    correct: 0,
    incorrect: 0,
    unanswered: 0,
    currentSet: 0,
    // "seen" property will keep track of the seen questions so we don't re-display them again
    seen: [],
    // Update: limit the number of question per game. Usong a property so you can change its value whenever you want to change the limit
    limit: 4,
    timer: 20,
    timerOn: false,
    timerId: "",
    // questions options and answers data
//me gustaria que la imagen se mostrará con cada pregunta que se hace
    questions: {
      q1: "Who is actually a chef?",
      q2: "What does Joey love to eat?",
      q3: "How many times has Ross been divorced?",
      q4: "How many types of towels does Monica have?",
      q5: "Who stole Monica's thunder after she got engaged?",
      q6: "Who hates Thanksgiving?",
      q7: "Who thinks they're always the last to find out everything?"
    },
//las respuestas muy extensas salen del container
    options: {
      q1: ["Monica", "Chandler", "Rachel", "Rosssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss"],
      q2: ["Fish", "Apples", "Oranges", "Sandwhiches"],
      q3: ["5", "2", "1", "3"],
      q4: ["3", "8", "11", "6"],
      q5: ["Rachel", "Phoebe", "Emily", "Carol"],
      q6: ["Joey", "Chandler", "Rachel", "Rosssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss"],
      q7: ["Ross", "Phoebe", "Monica", "Chandlerrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr"]
    },
    answers: {
      q1: "Monica",
      q2: "Sandwhiches",
      q3: "3",
      q4: "11",
      q5: "Rachel",
      q6: "Chandler",
      q7: "Phoebe"
    },
    // random number generator
    random: (min, max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min,
    startGame: function() {
      trivia.currentSet = 0;
      // set "seen" to an empty array for a new game
      trivia.seen = [];
      trivia.correct = 0;
      trivia.incorrect = 0;
      trivia.unanswered = 0;
      clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
      $("#game").show();
      $("#results").html("");
      $("#timer").text(trivia.timer);
      $("#start").hide();
      $("#remaining-time").show();
      trivia.nextQuestion();
    },
    nextQuestion: function() {
      trivia.timer = 10;
      $("#timer").removeClass("last-seconds");
      $("#timer").text(trivia.timer);
      if (!trivia.timerOn) {
        trivia.timerId = setInterval(trivia.timerRunning, 1000);
      }
      // get all the questions
      const qts = Object.values(trivia.questions);
      // init the random number
      let rq = null;
      // firstly, if no more questions to show set rq to -1 to let us know later that the game has finished 
      // Update: checking if we reached the "limit"
      if (trivia.seen.length >= trivia.limit) rq = -1
      else {
        // otherwise generate a random number from 0 inclusive to the length of the questions - 1 (as array indexing starts from 0 in JS) also inclusive
        do {
          // generate a random number using the newly added "random" method
          rq = trivia.random(0, qts.length - 1);
        } while (trivia.seen.indexOf(rq) != -1); // if the question is already seen then genrate another number, do that till we get a non-seen question index
        // add that randomly generated index to the seen array so we know that we have already seen it
        trivia.seen.push(rq);
        // increment the counter
        trivia.counter++;
      }
      // current question index is the generated random number "rq"
      trivia.currentSet = rq;
      var questionContent = Object.values(trivia.questions)[rq];
      $("#question").text(questionContent);
      var questionOptions = Object.values(trivia.options)[trivia.currentSet];
      $.each(questionOptions, function(index, key) {
        $("#options").append(
          $('<button class="option btn btn-info btn-lg">' + key + "</button>")
        );
      });
    },
    timerRunning: function() {
      if (
        trivia.timer > -1 &&
        // all the questions have already been seen
        // Update: now we check against the limit property
        trivia.seen.length < trivia.limit
    ) {
      $("#timer").text(trivia.timer);
      trivia.timer--;
      if (trivia.timer === 4) {
        $("#timer").addClass("last-seconds");
      }
    } else if (trivia.timer === -1) {
      trivia.unanswered++;
      trivia.result = false;
      clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
      resultId = setTimeout(trivia.guessResult, 1000);
      $("#results").html(
        "<h3>Out of time! The answer was " +
        Object.values(trivia.answers)[trivia.currentSet] +
        "</h3>"
      );
    }
    // if the game ended as we know that -1 means no more questions to display
    else if (trivia.currentSet === -1) {
      $("#results").html(
        "<h3>Thank you for playing!</h3>" +
        "<p>Correct: " +
        trivia.correct +
        "</p>" +
        "<p>Incorrect: " +
        trivia.incorrect +
        "</p>" +
        "<p>Unaswered: " +
        trivia.unanswered +
        "</p>" +
        "<p>Please play again!</p>"
      );
      $("#game").hide();
      $("#start").show();
    }
  },
  guessChecker: function() {
    var resultId;
    var currentAnswer = Object.values(trivia.answers)[trivia.currentSet];
    if ($(this).text() === currentAnswer) {
      //turn button green for correct
      $(this).addClass("btn-success").removeClass("btn-info");
      trivia.correct++;
      clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
      resultId = setTimeout(trivia.guessResult, 1000);
      $("#results").html("<h3>Correct Answer!</h3>");
    } else {
      $(this).addClass("btn-danger").removeClass("btn-info");

      trivia.incorrect++;
      clearInterval(trivia.timerId);
      resultId = setTimeout(trivia.guessResult, 1000);
      $("#results").html(
        "<h3>Better luck next time! " + currentAnswer + "</h3>"
      );
    }
  },

  guessResult: function() {
    // no need to increment trivia.currentSet anymore
    $(".option").remove();
    $("#results h3").remove();
    trivia.nextQuestion();
  }
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="header text-center clearfix">
    <h1 class="text-muted">Friends trivia game</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="game">
        <h2>FRIENDS Trivia Game</h2>
        <p id="remaining-time" class="lead">Remaining Time: <span id="timer"></span></p>
        <p id="question" class="lead"></p>
      </div>
      <div id="results">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div id="choices" class="text-center">
        <button id="start" class="btn btn-info btn-lg">Start Game</button>
        <div id="options">

        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- /container -->
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Lee los enlaces, es importante.. aca hay una pared de codigo gigante, y no explicas donde queres mostrar la imagen, de donde sale, o nada...

Comment: @gbianchi ya lo edité, me podrías ayudar?

Comment: Ya tienes arreglos para preguntas y respuestas, puedes usar otro para imágenes o, mejor aún, incluirlas en el arreglo de preguntas: `q1: ['The question?', 'the-image.jpg']`. Respecto a: _Y hacer que funcione para un teléfono celular_, necesitas ser más específico, ¿qué es lo que pasa cuando lo ves en celular?

Comment: Por otra parte, al tener las respuestas directamente en el código, va a ser muy fácil acertar a todas.

Comment: aveces las respuestas son muy larga y se salen del container.

Comment: q1: ['The question?', 'the-image.jpg'] lo hice así pero no pasa nada.

Comment: Saludos. A salvedad no lo vi; te hace falta incluir la estructura de donde se tomará las imágenes; asumo que son imágenes (ruta y archivo) conocidas; asi mismo no hay el tag `img` que la presentaria ni el detalle respecto al problema que al respecto tienes.

Comment: I already tried doing it that way but it didn't work

Comment: can you show me your code

Answer (score 0):

Primero crea una nueva etiqueta en tu HTML para almacenar la imágen que vayas a colocar. Luego prueba creando una nueva variable tipo string, vacía para almacenar posteriormente la ruta a una imagen y tambien crea un nuevo objeto para almacenar las rutas a las imagenes que quieras usar.
Al momento de hacer el random para seleccionar la pregunta, pudieras hacer otro random para seleccionar la imagen, (si lo que quieres es seleccionar imagenes diferentes para todas las preguntas, osea, que cada vez que te salga la pregunta 3, la imagen sea diferente... si quieres que la imagen para la pregunta 3 sea la misma te puede servir lo que dice Triby más arriba).
Entonces con el resultado numerico de ese random haces un switch y evalúas dicho resultado para, basandote en ese valor, asignar a la variable string vacía (que te dije que crearas) cierto valor del objeto que te dije que contendría la ruta de las imagenes.
Pero si no me doy a entender muy bien, espero que con un poco de código entiendas mejor mi idea.

```css
HTML

//estableces la ruta de la imagen en el atributo SRC de la etiqueta IMG en el DOM
$("img").setAttibute("src",random_img);
```

```html
JAVASCRIPT

random_img: '';
img {
    1: 'ruta_img-1',
    2: 'ruta_img_2,
    3: ruta_img_3'
}
rq= 3 /*resultado de la seleccion random que estás haciendo, no se como la haces pero supongamos que la funcion te devolvió 3*/

switch(rq):     //accedes a los valores del objeto y lo                 //asignas a la variable creada
case 1: 
    random_img= img.1;
    break;
case 2:
    random_img= img.2;
```

Espero que te ayude en algo.